# Symfony2 - where are all the places where the 'secret' key (parameters.yml) is used?

Tags: symfony

I need to be 100% on exactly how many places the secret key is used in Symfony2.

This may be an obvious question, such as 'wherever you specify it with %secret% in the Yaml file', but I need to be 100% sure it's not being used by the internal Symfony code somewhere.

(1) Is it used at all with the database? I see it's in parameters.yml and underneath the DB settings, but I can't see how it can be used by the DB. I'm using Doctrine2.

(2) I can think of all these places, are there any more?

- anywhere it is called in PHP with getParameter('param_name');
- anywhere using %secret% in a Yaml file
- especially likely to be used in security.yml to generate a cookie for the remember_me login option

Have I missed any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) basically it's only used to generate CSRF token

2) The parameter's name is kernel.secret